# Nomenclature of a fused tricyclic hydrocarbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

What is the preferred IUPAC name of the compound shown below (and its common name, if there is one)?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to Subsection P-25.1.1 of the  current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001), the preferred name of the parent structure, which formally results from the *ortho-* and *peri*-fusion of benzene and naphthalene, is the retained name ‘phenalene’. In order to indicate the position where no multiple bond is attached, an italic capital ‘*H*’ preceded by a numerical locant is added to the front of the name. According to Subsection P-25.7.1.3.1, indicated hydrogen may be omitted in general nomenclature and 1⁠*H*-phenalene may be called just ‘phenalene’. In a
preferred IUPAC name (PIN), however, a locant and the symbol ‘*H*’ must be cited.

[image: 2,3,3a,3a1,4,5,6,6a,7,9a-decahydro-1⁠H-phenalene]

The corresponding (partly) saturated compound can be described by using the prefix ‘hydro’, which indicates the addition of hydrogen.

[image: 1,1,2,5-tetramethyl-2,3,3a,3a1,4,5,6,6a,7,9a-decahydro-1⁠H-phenalene]

The four methyl substituents of the compound given in the question are cited as prefixes in substitutive nomenclature, which yields the name 1,1,2,5-tetramethyl-2,3,3a,3a<sup>1</sup>,4,5,6,6a,7,9a-decahydro-1⁠*H*-phenalene.

[image: 1H-phenalene]